# How to express my sold items are diverse?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, synonyms

In Czech, I would say there is a *varied offer*, would that be correct? What about *diverse, various, miscellaneous, multifarious*?

Also, I didn't find any synonyms to *offer* in the business sense. Are there any?

> **Example:** The more varied the offer is, the harder it is to target a single target group in your marketing.

Comment: sell, sold, sold: my sold items. irregular verb. adjective: the greater your product **mix**. That's the marketing term.

Comment: I think you mean to say **The items I have for sale** or **My items up for sale** or **items to be sold**.   We don't really have an adjective that can be used before **items** which means "up for sale", except in a roundabout way, such as "My listed items".  The noun **merchandise** is generally understood to mean *items for sale*.

Comment: **diverse** is apt.

Answer (score 0):

The more diverse|varied the merchandise (for sale), the more difficult|costly it becomes to target potential customers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more usual in English to refer to a "**large variety** of *something*".

> The **larger offer you have**, the harder it is to target a single target group in your marketing.

As pointed by @Lambie in a comment, you can use "product mix":

> The bigger the **product mix**, the harder it is to target a single target group in your **marketing strategy**.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine, except I would strike "is"; I would try to eliminate one use of "target"; and I would use a different word for "single", like "specific" or "individual":

> The more varied the offer, the harder it is to reach a specific target group in your marketing.

That said, while you can say that an offer is "varied", you typically don't call it a "varied offer". You might call it a "miscellaneous offer," but "miscellaneous" is really describing the offer, not the things being offered. You typically use a different construct with words like "various" and "variety".

I don't really have any sources to back up my claims but I can provide a few more examples:

> My reasons for wanting to leave are varied.
>
> I have various reasons for wanting to leave.
>
> I have a variety of reasons for wanting to leave.
>
> I have varied reasons for wanting to leave. <-- LESS COMMON

---

> The sizes and colors of the clothes are varied.
>
> The clothes come in various sizes and colors.
>
> The clothes come in a variety of sizes and colors.
>
> The clothes come in varied sizes and colors. <-- LESS COMMON